# Can not cancel current navigation and navigate elsewhere from root component

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular2-routing

When a user is not logged into my application which is equal to that there exists no `userToken` in the localStorage then I just want to redirect him to the login route.

Lets say the user enters the route `/customers` then he should be redirected to the login screen when there exist no `userToken` in the local storage.

**`App.component.ts`:**

```
export class AppComponent
{
  constructor(private routerService: RouterService, private router: Router, private authService: AuthenticationService)
  {
    if (!authService.isLoggedIn())
    {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }
}
```

The router navigate method is called but it is not navigating to the login screen, why not? The customers data on backend is tried to fetch, but I get a 401 in the server response. That means the code after... the root app component just continued to run.

Comment: You should also remove the token before navigate called I think ? There will be curcular redirection may be

Comment: And you are doing it in root component its not right it will execute only once since the app is loaded use canActivate for this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: Right you are, but when I subscribe to route changes in the app component it should work. I just try that!

Comment: In your current code two things are wrong the root constructor will be executed only once in whole life second user should be restricted before landing on any route so put it inside canactivate 3rd you should also check if user is already on login then no redirection required

Comment: ok i thought I could hack it... seems than I have to use the guards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to angular 2 check user is login or not before going through route.you can use 'canActivate' in route define like this

```
{ path: 'customers', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] }
```

And now on AuthService you can defined method

```
canActivate() {
        //you can check token is exists or not here 
        if (localstorage.getItem('user')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

More details h[ttps://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I thought about this, but did not want to put 10 activate methods everywhere... instead one single place is neater - if it works -

Comment: I just want to do the isLoggedIn call ONE time at ONE place whenever a route changes.

Comment: you can pass in all your route defined with , canActivate: [AuthService] it's every time check when route is changed

Comment: yes I go that route the other was too hacky. Somehow I was confused that I had to write kind of 10 activations... haha, btw. why do you logoout, when the user is not logged in/authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

This code will never work.

```
if (!authService.isLoggedIn())
{
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

You should call the service to preauthorize a user before. But you are checking the state of service that is not defined yet.

Comment: The authService instance is created, there is not the problem.

Comment: And this will execute only once since app is started

Comment: and what you would like saying?